# Merge contacts.app and address-book tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Two seemingly identical tags:

- [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app)

  Tag wiki:

  > Apple's address book client, renamed from Address Book in OS X 10.8
- [address-book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address-book)

  Tag wiki:

  > Apple's built-in contacts manager software for Mac OS X.

  As the [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app) tag wiki clearly states, it is a simple rename of the same thing.

Feature Request: Merge the two, and create a synonym for the other.

---

**Edit**:  I'm not saying these are the *only* tags that need it - go ahead and merge the others as well! :)

- [address-book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address-book) → [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app)
- [ical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ical) → [calender](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calender)
- [ichat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ichat) → [messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messages)

Comment: It hasn't even been called Address Book since Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion".

Comment: Haha - yeah.  Overdue, wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: I will create "address-book" as tag synonym for "contacts" as soon I can as I'm one vote short on my answers for "contacts"-tagged posts in order to create tag synonyms for it. I do agree that the tags need to be merged, as all it is is an old name for Contacts.app.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is that this is a good thing, but I'm not convinced about what I feel about this, particularly if you're limiting this to the tags in your question.

There's a few tags that exist like this, where the different tags refer to different versions of the software, delineated by its name change.

- [address-book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address-book) → [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app)
- [ical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ical) → [calendar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)
- [ichat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ichat) → [messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messages)

If you're going to synonym one pair, might as well synonym all the pairs?

Comment: What other pairs are like this?

Comment: @Red Updated answer

Comment: I think we should merge all the pairs of tags you mentioned. None of them have used their name since 10.7. I don't think that we should have separate vote counts for the same software under an old name.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted address-book as a tag synonym suggestion for the contacts tag. However, it still needs 4 votes by those that have 5 votes or more in the contacts tags in order to actually become a tag synonym. If it reaches a vote of -2 the suggestion will be deleted, though.

[image]